# One django instance one database vs different django instances

Tags: python, django, deployment

I am building a software that will store and manage doctor's data. I would like to ask something that came to me and has to do with how I want to deploy my project. At first I wanted to have different django instance for each client. Each clinet would have his own database and run seperatelly from the others. But I am not sure I can automate this procedure, because for each instance I need to have different database, different password different db username, something that I am not sure It can be automated  while creating a every new instance of my django project. Or is it in some way. Imagine the following scenario

```
User pays -> After successfull payment -> DB(MySQL) is created -> 
django instance is created -> 
somehow django settings file is updated with db credentials -> syncdb is run
```

and this procedure must be automated. Is it better to have one db with and the seperation to be done from models (with foreignkeys etc)? Or is one unified database not a good solution (security side)? What do you think?

Comment: Managing different instances will be a tedious task involving different steps which may fail if something goes wrong. My advice is to use a single database and separate clients by making different users.

Comment: Could that lead to security issues?

Comment: What security issues are you concerned about? You can create different tables in the database with different permissions.

Comment: different tables?But there will be one model for one instance correct?Like one patient model (table) with records(rows) that belong to different practices. What do u mean by different tables?

Comment: You could create different models for both clients or you could create a single model for bot clients.

Comment: Hopefully there will be more than two clients :). I didn't say I would have 2 clients (you write the word both on your comment). It should work for as many clients the system has.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51733/discussion-between-dhiraj-thakur-and-apostolos)

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can have a look on multi-tenant data architecture.

https://github.com/bernardopires/django-tenant-schemas

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx

Comment: I will look in to it.. Do I need to have each model of mine belong to the seperate tenant using foreignkeys?...Didn't get it from the tutorial.

Comment: Because your table structure will become something like "SchemaA.TableA", "SchemaB.TableA", so as long as you get the "Schema" right, i think foreignkeys might not needed.

Comment: I will try to figure it out...It doesn't explain how it creates new database if you use seperate db's.