# Django deployment, Multi project vs multi-user

Tags: python, django, deployment

I have a Django project that is a small ERP for dentists. Everything is ready working appart from one very important think. Since this django project will be sold to different clients, I came to think of two approaches.

1. Each client runs his own independent project (different settings file, db, project folder etc)
2. One project and each client is a seperate model, that exists as a foreignkey to my models to distinguish to which client my model instances belong.

All this must take in to considereation that the creation of a new client should be done automatically. For the first one I thought the solution of openshift. Openshift gives me an API that i can create start applications automatically using the same git repository. So i can have

- client1.mydomain.com
- client2.mydomain.com
- client3.mydomain.com etc

The problem with this method is that I must be able to manage as many as different applications I have and i am not sure what happens if i push changes to the git repository. WIll all applications see it?( I am thinking probably).

The second method lets me handle only one project but I am not sure about privacy issues. E.g if i have a url like this `mydomain.com/doctor_id/patient_id`, what is stopping doctor with id 3 to see patients of doctor with id 5 e.g. The same with images. If i have one MEDIA_URL and one MEDIA_DIR what is stopping (or how) a doctor seeing other doctor's patients pictures? What would you suggest on that?

[This was proposed too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23409666/2349589) but won't change i think the access problem. I guess it could be done manually, like check if the patient of image requested belongs to the user logged in, but I was thinking a more built in mechanism (if there is any).

Comment: I don't think this is a django issue per sé, but rather a software architecture problem

Comment: Reminds me a bit of the question I once asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970872/

Comment: I accidentally answered on your question. But tenants won't make sure that a doctor can access a url with the id from another doctor, because of the urls.py and the common settings file thus common MEDIA_URL and MEDIA_DIR right?